# locus of smooth points in Hilbert scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

For the Hilbert scheme of points $\operatorname{Hilb}^n_d$ we define the smoothable component $Smbl^n_d$ to be the closure of the "locus of smooth subschemes". But what exactly is this locus? Does it only contain those closed points $[R]$ of $\operatorname{Hilb}^n_d$ such that $R$ is smooth? Or does it also contain some other points which are not closed? I am confused about the term "locus" here.

Many thanks.

Comment: Take the set of all closed  points representing smooth $R$s, called the locus of smooth points. This set may not be closed in Hilb, so we may take its closure. You may also wish to take all smooth points (closed or otherwise) and take its closure in Hilb. These two are the same.

Comment: Okay, thank you!